# Utilize Janusgraph indexes when searching for value already in graph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to use a composite index to retrieve vertices with a property equaling a certain value. However, the value I am testing for is in the graph, and I need to do this all in one transaction. I understand this is confusing so let me give my situation in further detail:

I currently have a property key defined called 'type'. I have a composite index on this key across the whole graph. This allows me to do things like `g.V().has("type", "value")` utilizing this index.

However, "value" now is actually a value on a map I have injected. So I have this:

```
g.inject([prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2"])
 .unfold().select(values).as("vals")
 .V().filter(values("type").where(eq("vals")))
```

This works, but it does not use my index on 'type'. Is there a way I can utilize the index but still filter my vertices by a value on a map that was injected into the traversal? Even utilizing a mixed index in this case would be fine, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.